# Best Sorting OpenCL algorithm

Tags: sorting, opencl

I am writing code in OpenCL for AMD APU (northern island GPU) and AMD evergreen GPU. I have to sort a huge array of integers and I have to do it efficiently (less memory usage and least execution time). Which sorting algorithm should I use for this purpose?

Comment: Mergesort seems like a reasonable choice. It's easily parallelizable, fairly simple and lightweight, requires only sequential access, doesn't rely on randomness, and has optimal worst-case asymptotic complexity (and is generally pretty fast).

Comment: Thank you Thomas! Should I write it myself or any fast sample implementation is already there?

Comment: I suppose existing implementations are available, but it would be an interesting exercise in OpenCL to write it yourself if you have time to do so. The algorithm maps rather well to GPGPU concepts so it's not excruciatingly difficult either.

Comment: Yeah you are right.I have written Mergesort for an array having multiple of 2 number of elements. Since my objective is to use a sorted array and do more stuff so I didn't want to spend time on something that has already been done. If the implementations already there are more efficient, I would definitely want to use them.

Comment: Bitonic Sort is well suited for parallel architectures. The sample code comes with AMD SDK APP